# Create password digest in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, soap, ws-security

I am working in integrating DigestPassword web service in my iPhone application. For this purpose I need to generate nonce and passwordDigest. I tried hard but I could not find any working example in Google search.

I have done it following way:   **Updated Code:**

```
NSString *user = @"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
NSNumber *nonce = @(arc4random());
NSLog(@"nonce %@",[self encodeStringTo64:[nonce stringValue]]);
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
NSString *created = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"created %@",created);
NSString *digest_concat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", nonce, created, @"Pwd@123"];

NSData *digestBytes = [self shaa1:digest_concat];
NSString *digestBase64 = [self base64forData:digestBytes];
NSLog(@"digestBase64 %@",digestBase64);

NSString *strSOAP = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:v1=\"http://sita.aero/iborders/external/ReferralManagementServiceWSDLType/V1\"><soap:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\" xmlns:wsu=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\"><wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id=\"UsernameToken-27E173B8CF239BE6F01440582357416191\"><wsse:Username>%@</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest\">%@</wsse:Password><wsse:Nonce EncodingType=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary\">%@</wsse:Nonce><wsu:Created>%@</wsu:Created></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></soap:Header><soap:Body><v1:SearchReferralsRequest><v1:ReferralSearchCriteria><ReferralId>2038100</ReferralId></v1:ReferralSearchCriteria><v1:Paging><FetchNumber>1</FetchNumber><ResultsPerFetch>1</ResultsPerFetch></v1:Paging></v1:SearchReferralsRequest></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>",user,digestBase64,[self encodeStringTo64:[nonce stringValue]],created];

- (NSString*)encodeStringTo64:(NSString*)fromString{
    NSData *plainData = [fromString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *base64String;
    if ([plainData respondsToSelector:@selector(base64EncodedStringWithOptions:)]) {
        base64String = [plainData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:kNilOptions];  // iOS 7+
    } else {
        base64String = [plainData base64Encoding];                              // pre iOS7
    }
    return base64String;
}

- (NSData *)shaa1:(NSString *)input {
NSData *data = [input dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
uint8_t digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CC_SHA1(data.bytes, (CC_LONG) data.length, digest);
return [NSData dataWithBytes:digest length:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
```

}

Can someone please check my code for creating nonce and password digest and let me know what mistake I am making as I am not able to access web service with this? I am always getting **Message Expired** error.
Error:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <soap:Code>
            <soap:Value>soap:Sender</soap:Value>
            <soap:Subcode>
               <soap:Value xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">ns1:MessageExpired</soap:Value>
            </soap:Subcode>
         </soap:Code>
         <soap:Reason>
            <soap:Text xml:lang="en">The message has expired</soap:Text>
         </soap:Reason>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Edit: My Desired SOAP Request:**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:v1="http://xxxxx/xxxx/external/ServiceWSDLType/V1">
 <soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-XXXXX">
          <wsse:Username>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</wsse:Username>
          <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">iAdbggkXsbNih5wBJ8M2tyyVWiA=</wsse:Password>
          <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">b8SD2g2iiVvihx7ajVwPfw==</wsse:Nonce>
          <wsu:Created>2015-08-28T07:16:04.857Z</wsu:Created>
       </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
 </soap:Header>
 <soap:Body>
    <v1:SearchReferralsRequest>
       <v1:ReferralSearchCriteria>
          <ReferralId>213213</ReferralId>
       </v1:ReferralSearchCriteria>
       <v1:Paging>
          <FetchNumber>1</FetchNumber>
          <ResultsPerFetch>1</ResultsPerFetch>
       </v1:Paging>
    </v1:SearchReferralsRequest>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Could you check server logs for more information about error?

Comment: yes, it is working from SOAPUI but I am not able to replicate same in objective c code

Comment: I think you need to show your complete SOAP request in your question.

Comment: I have added desired soap request but somehow I am not able to format it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to send SHA1 digest without additional encoding into hex string.

Try this function for SHA1:

```
- (NSData *)sha1:(NSString *)input {
    NSData *data = [input dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA1(data.bytes, (CC_LONG) data.length, digest);
    return [NSData dataWithBytes:digest length:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
}
```

Also check that time value in password digest is the same as `wsu:Created`.

Update #1

Also you use base64 nonce in password digest but in documentation formula is:

> Password_Digest = Base64 ( SHA-1 ( nonce + created + password ) )

So nonce must be number, not base64 encoded number. Try this password digest code:

```
NSNumber *nonce = @(arc4random());

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
NSString *created = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSString *digest_concat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", nonce, created, password];
```

Update #2

Looks like you have expired message because of time zone. From specification **Web Services Security: SOAP Message Security Version 1.1.1**:

> This specification defines and illustrates time references in terms of
>   the xsd:dateTime type defined in XML Schema.  It is RECOMMENDED that
>   all time references use this type.  All references MUST be in UTC
>   time. Implementations MUST NOT generate time instants that specify
>   leap seconds. If, however, other time types are used, then the
>   ValueType attribute (described below) MUST be specified to indicate
>   the data type of the time format. Requestors and receivers SHOULD NOT
>   rely on other applications supporting time resolution finer than
>   milliseconds.

Use UTC time zone:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
NSString *created = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: I tried this but I am not getting result similar to SOAPUI

Comment: And with your implementation you getting same result as SOAPUI?

Comment: To test my programme I generate nonce, date and password from soapui but I don't submit it(it works if I submit the request). I then use same nonce and created date in my programme to get the response. It is not matching with digest password generated with soapui.

Comment: I have updated my request as per your suggestions. The request that is generated now looks similar to what generated by SOAPUI but it is still not working and I am getting same Message Expired error. Please check updated code above.

Comment: Hi John, thanks a lot, I had been stuck on this issue for about a week and your suggestion of using UTC timezone fixed it for me. I am surprised I could never found this anywhere on the internet. You have been my saviour on this... I wish I could offer you a beer :)